# Bootstrap Signin Template - Add Alerts

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the Bootstrap v4.1 Signin Template (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sign-in/) for a simple login form - I need to add some alerts if the user's login was invalid. I've added an Alert after the login form but when this displays it has moved the login form to the left and the error message appears on the right - I'm trying to get this to appear below (or above) the signing form, but haven't used this template before.

Here's an example showing this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

  <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="../../../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="text-center">
  <form class="form-signin">
    <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
  </form>

  <main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p class="text-center">Ther was an error with your login - please try again</p>
    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- /.container -->


</body>

</html>
```

Not sure how to include Alerts with this Signin form so the form and the alert both display correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your alert inside the form.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

  <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="../../../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="text-center">
  <form class="form-signin">
    <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    
    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
      <p class="text-center">Ther was an error with your login - please try again</p>
    </div>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a shallow testing, it seems that "display:flex" in css's body could be your problem.